# Use Trigonometry in Bash

Tags: bash, trigonometry

I'm trying to write a bash script that calculates Wind Correction Angles, but I run into an error whenever I run the trig part of the script.

```
line 32: sin(-14): syntax error in expression (error token is "(-14)"
```

I know the full formula for WCA isn't on there yet, but I wanted to get the trig resolved before continuing. The script is posted below. If there's any other details needed, I'll be happy to oblige. Cheers

```
#!/bin/bash

# This script is to be used in Cross Country calculations

echo 'What is True Course?'

read true_course

echo 'What is True Airspeed?'

read true_airspeed

echo 'What is Wind Direction?'

read wind_direction

echo 'What is Wind Speed?'

read wind_speed

# Formula for WCA is below
# WCA = sin-1 (sin(WD-TC)*WV/TAS)

course_adjustment=$(($wind_direction-$true_course))

course_adjustment2=$(($course_adjustment*$wind_speed/$true_airspeed))

wca=$((sin($course_adjustment2)))

echo 'Course adjustment is' $course_adjustment
echo 'Course adjustment2 is' $course_adjustment2

# Formula for GS
# GS = SqRt(TAS2 + WV2 - 2*TAS*WV*cos(WD-TC-WCA))

echo 'Calculations complete!'

echo 'True Course is' $true_course

echo 'True Airspeed is' $true_airspeed

echo 'Wind Direction is' $wind_direction

echo 'Wind Speed is' $wind_speed
```

Comment: bash only supports integer arithmetic. Usually you farm out stuff needing floating point to something else like `bc` or `awk` or whatever else provides the needed functionality.

Comment: Always post errors... And do not expect someone to just do the work for you. Show your effort resolving your own issues..

Comment: See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/022 for some examples and suggestions. (Sounds like ksh93 instead of bash might be one easy route, if that's an option)

Comment: Realized that I should as soon as I hit 'post'

Comment: A shell is the worst tool for floating point arithmetic. In particular, it has no trigonometric functions. You should use a tool that fits the problem domain. Better suited: python, perl, maybe C or Java.

Answer (score 2):

[Bash's arithmetic support is limited to integers](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Arithmetic.html), so you cannot do trigonometry in pure Bash.

Further, Bash's arithmetic context doesn't support any notion of functions, let along trig functions, which is why you're seeing that odd-sounding error. `$((sin($course_adjustment2)))` is equivalent to `$(($sin($course_adjustment2)))` (variables in arithmetic contexts don't need a `$`, so it's looking for a `$sin` variable).

The general way to do floating point arithmetic in Bash (other than [not using Bash at all](http://google.github.io/styleguide/shellguide.html#s1.2-when-to-use-shell), why not Python?) is with [`bc`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_mono/bc.html), as Shawn suggested.

```sh
# note the -l argument; s[ine] and c[osine] arguments are in radians 
$ bc -l <<<"scale=4; s(1); c(1)"
.8414
.5404
```